# Button add dynamic div

Tags: javascript, php, html, dynamic

Hello I'm making a table using divs. I want to append in each div using a button. For instance I have a `sunday` div and in it I wish to append each row in. here what is look like http://jsfiddle.net/vFEd5/1/ . My button `add row` is disabled cause I don't know how to do it. So when I click `add row` I need to append *project* and *lieu* in `sunday`. How should I do this?

my code :

```
<div class="Table">
    <div class="Title">
        <p>Feuille de temps</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Heading">
        <div class="Cell">
            <p>Jour de la semaine</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell">
            <p>projet</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell">
            <p>lieu</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Row">
        <div class="jour">
            <p>dimanche</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell">
                   <p>  <input type="text" name="projet1" size="10" id ="projet2" class "lieu"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell">
            <p> <input type="text" name="prolieu1" size="10" id ="lieu1" class "lieu"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Row">
        <div class="jour" >
            <p>lundi</p>
        </div>

        <div class="Cell">
             <p>    <input type="text" name="projet3" size="10" id ="projet3" class "lieu"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell">
            <p> <input type="text" name="prolieu2" size="10" id ="lieu2" class "lieu"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

     <input type="button" onclick="addRows();" value="Add Row" />






<style type="text/css">
    .Table
    {
        display: table;
    }
    .Title
    {
        display: table-caption;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: larger;
    }
    .Heading
    {
        display: table-row;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .Row
    {
        display: table-row;
    }
    .Cell
    {
        display: table-cell;
        border: solid;
        border-width: thin;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
    }
        .jour
    {

        display: table-row;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
```

my code for autocomplete, I'll add it later

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).keydown(function(event){
    if( (event.keyCode == 13) && (validationFunction() == false) ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  });
});


});

    //------------------AUTO COMPLETE NUMÉRO DE PROJET----------------------    
                $(document).ready(function(){
            //-------AUTO COMPLETE addrow PROJET-----
                    $("#name").autocomplete({
                        source:'name[].php',
                        minLength:1
                    });
    //------------------COMPLETE addrow DESC DIMANCHE----------------------
                function handleEnter(e, obj, field){

                    if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.which == 13){
                        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                          }
                        else
                          {// code for IE6, IE5
                            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                          }
                        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                          {
                            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                                {
                                    tempArrayInJS = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText); 
                                    $("#client1[]").val( tempArrayInJS[0]['cliName']);

                                }
                          }
                        xmlhttp.open("GET","completeclient.php?q="+obj.value,true);
                        xmlhttp.send();

                    }
```

Comment: Tip: open console and you will see that there is an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: addRows is not defined`.

Comment: I know is not define cause I'm not sure how to do this. This is why I'm saying addrow button for the moment is not working. cause I've not any function for the moment I need help for this.

Comment: You can split your css and HTML files in seperate files. Thats alot better. Like main.css f.e.

Comment: You want to use an array for the `name` attribute, i.e. `prolieu[]` instead of `prolieu2`. It would make your life much easier when you process it.

Comment: I have a question: what day is it supposed to add ? If lundi is the previous day, should mardi automatically be calculated ?

Comment: @aduch for the moment I'm trying sunday and monday after eventualy i'll add all the week.I just want to append sunday lieu and project. with one button. 

Dissident Rage: is easier than div ?

Xatenev: I'll do it in my main code this is just a test and if it work i'll duplicated in my real code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change from

```
  <div class="Row">
    <div class="jour">
        <p>dimanche</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Cell">

    </div>
    <div class="Cell">

    </div>
</div>
```

to

```
   <div class="Row">
    <div class="jour">
        <p>dimanche</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Cell" id="dimancheProject">

    </div>
    <div class="Cell" id="dimancheLieu">

    </div>
</div>
```

and then try this in your JS file :

```
    var i=0;
function addRow(){
    var dimancheProject = document.getElementById("dimancheProject");
    var dimancheLieu = document.getElementById("dimancheLieu");

    var projectParagraph = document.createElement('p');
    var lieuParagraph = document.createElement('p');
    var inputLieu = document.createElement('input');
    var inputProject = document.createElement('input');
    inputProject.type = 'text';
    inputProject.class="lieu";
    inputProject.size="10";
    inputProject.id='project'+i;
    inputProject.name='project'+i;

    inputLieu.type = 'text';
    inputLieu.class="lieu";
    inputLieu.size="10";
    inputLieu.id='lieu'+i;
    inputLieu.name='lieu'+i;

    projectParagraph.appendChild(inputProject);
    lieuParagraph.appendChild(inputLieu);

    dimancheProject.appendChild(projectParagraph);
    dimancheLieu.appendChild(lieuParagraph);
    i++;
}
```

NB : Don't forget to adapt your table CSS when adding elements !

Comment: add problem they day addwors is not defines in this line :   <input type="button" onclick="addRows();" value="Add Row" /> after I added your code

Comment: When I've added your code they give me this error :  <input type="button" onclick="addRows();"  addrows is not defined.

Comment: Where did you add it ? it must be added in a javascript file referenced in your HTML page header, or added via the <script> tag in your html code

Comment: I added your script in my header but this is the error It's give me

Comment: Updated my script, better now, you can find it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vFEd5/16/) in your Fiddle updated, I added the script in the header of the HTML code

Comment: work perfectly that was I'm looking for now time to learn and understand the code to reused it! Great thanks! Add little question If I used the function autcomplete I show in my edit code do you whink it will work?

Comment: You're welcome ! Sorry dude but I don't know anything about JQuery =)

Comment: It's simple to reemove new rows?

Comment: Very easy dude : document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(rowNumber); aaaaand it's done !

Comment: Two question its is better doing an remove button when I add row with your code or add a button to the end and remove previous row?

Comment: It doesn't matter I think, it is as you wish. I think a button at the end of the row is more sexy :p

Comment: so I need to make a dynamic button remove at the end of the row and make this line of code ? document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(rowNumber)

Comment: All you have to do is insert in my code a line that creates a button, and add this button the deleteRow function. Ask another question in a new thread not to spam this one

Comment: the button itself disapear haha.

Answer (score 1):

This method calculates your day from monday if no row already exists, if you want to allow later to choose manually the day it should be easier.

I removed from your dom p elements containing input as this is not allowed by HTML semantics, you may see that input width is different from those added manually, but this is css so I didn't bother and focused on the main problem.

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/axelduch/vFEd5/9/)

```
function addRows() {
    'use strict';
    var table = document.getElementById('calendarTable'),
        row = document.createElement('div'),
        cell = row.cloneNode(false),
        day = row.cloneNode(false),
        p = document.createElement('p'),
        input = document.createElement('input'),
        rows =  table.querySelectorAll('.Row'),
        rowCount = rows.length,
        days = ['lundi', 'mardi', 'mercredi', 'jeudi', 'vendredi', 'samedi', 'dimanche'],
        newDayIndex = 0; // lundi by default

    // build jour cell
    day.className = 'jour';

    // calculate next day
    if (rowCount) {
        newDayIndex = (days.indexOf(rows[rowCount-1].querySelector('.jour p').innerHTML) + 1) % days.length;
    }

    p.innerHTML = days[newDayIndex];
    day.appendChild(p);
    row.appendChild(day);

    // build projet and lieu cells
    cell.className = 'Cell';
    input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    input.setAttribute('name', 'projet_' + rowCount);
    input.setAttribute('id', 'projet_' + rowCount);
    input.className = 'projet';
    cell.appendChild(input);
    row.appendChild(cell);

    cell = cell.cloneNode(false);
    cell.className = 'Cell';
    input = input.cloneNode(false);
    input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    input.setAttribute('name', 'lieu_' + rowCount);
    input.setAttribute('id', 'lieu_' + rowCount);
    input.className = 'lieu';
    cell.appendChild(input);
    row.appendChild(cell);

    // then row
    row.className = 'Row';

    table.appendChild(row);

}
```

Comment: almost that ! but when I append for sunday I want to have all my sunday in order, all my friday in order. like : sunday project 1, lieu 1. If I click on add button.sunday lieu 1 project 1 , lieu 2 project 2. I will have seven button for each day cause I don't know how many project the client will do in each day

Answer (score 0):

You could try using jQuery for this kind of DOM manipulation: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vFEd5/7/)

```
var week = ["dimanche", "lundi", "vendredi", "mardi", "mercredi", "jeudi", "samedi"];

addRows = function () {
    var numberOfDays = $(".Row").length;
    console.log(numberOfDays);
    var row = $('<div class="Row"></div>');
    var cell1 = $('<div class="Cell"></div>');
    var cell2 = $('<div class="Cell"></div>');
    row = row.append('<div class="jour"><p>' + week[numberOfDays % 7] + '</p></div>');
    row = row.append(cell1.append('<p><input type="text" name="projet' + (numberOfDays + 1) + '" size="10" id="projet' + (numberOfDays + 1) + '" class="lieu" /></p>'));
    row = row.append(cell2.append('<p><input type="text" name="prolieu' + (numberOfDays) + '" size="10" id="lieu"' + (numberOfDays) + '" class="lieu" /></p>'));
    $('.Table').append(row);
};
```

Comment: If i doit like this can projet and prolieu have my function autcomplete?

Comment: @TheBaconManWithouBacon What is your function autocomplete function? You didn't mention it in your question.